# Null Pointer exception while initializing Object using "new" keyword in springboot based microservcies

Tags: spring, web-services

What happens when I build an object using new keyword in service using springboot framework?

Does the Object created using "new" keyword is built out of the container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

No, the object created out of a "new" keyword doesn't come out of the container. There are two disadvantages to this approach. The first being that it renders the Spring framework a bit useless. Secondly, if there are @Autowired or Spring managed beans inside your "new" bean, they won't get injected. Once you do a "new", spring leaves all the subsequent hierarchical dependency injection to you.

Answer (score 0):

in Spring, objects that are created using new keyword, created outside of the container. So you wouldn't get benefits like life cycle management, Security etc

Answer (score 0):

You should always use Spring dependency injection to create Beans (using the @Autowired annotation is the recommended way to do this) otherwise you're losing the benefits of using the Spring framework. I would suggest reading [this documentation on Beans and Dependency Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html) if you haven't already